# Edit values and update in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this time i want to  `edit` and `update` the new values in Firebase Database. I have read the firebase documentation and followed the steps. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

i need a litte orientation, following the documentation's steps i have modifed my POJO class,
as proof just add the `interno` key in the  `public Map<>...`

```
public class Cow implements Serializable {
    String interno;
 


    public Cow() {
    }

    public Cow(String interno) {
        this.interno = interno;
        
    }
    public String getInterno() {
        return interno;
    }

    public void setInterno(String interno) {
        this.interno = interno;
    }

    
    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("inte", interno);
        return result;
    }

}
```

This is my database in firebase

[image]

I have a `recyclerview` and I send the values to another activity by an intent, where i show the details, **in this detailcow i want to modify the values**.

This is the code:

```
public class Cowdetail extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference reference;
    EditText tvinterno, tvsiniiga, tvpadre, tvmadre, tvnacimiento, tvinseminacion, tvtoro, tvestatus, tvnotas;
    AppCompatImageView tvimage;
    Button tvbutton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detailcow);

        tvinterno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvinterno);
        tvsiniiga = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvsiniiga);
        tvpadre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvpadre);
        tvmadre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvmadre);
        tvnacimiento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvnacimiento);
        tvinseminacion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvinsemincion);
        tvtoro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvtoro);
        tvestatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvestatus);
        tvnotas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvnotas);
        tvimage = (AppCompatImageView) findViewById(R.id.tvimage);
        tvbutton = findViewById(R.id.actualizar);

        String vpadre = "";
        String vmadre = "";
        String vinterno = "";
        String vsiniiga = "";
        String vnacimiento = "";
        String vinseminacion = "";
        String vtoro = "";
        String vestatus = "";
        String vnotas = "";
        String vurl;


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras !=null);
        vinterno = extras.getString("keyint");
        vsiniiga = extras.getString("keysin");
        vmadre = extras.getString("madre");
        vpadre = extras.getString("padre");
        vnacimiento = extras.getString("nacimiento");
        vinseminacion = extras.getString("inseminacion");
        vtoro = extras.getString("toro");
        vestatus = extras.getString("estatus");
        vnotas = extras.getString("notas");
        String image = extras.getString("img");
        if (image == null|| image.isEmpty()){
            tvimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_imageinf);
        } else {
            Picasso.get().load(image).fit().centerCrop().into(tvimage);
        }

        tvpadre.setText(vpadre);
        tvinterno.setText(vinterno);
        tvsiniiga.setText(vsiniiga);
        tvmadre.setText(vmadre);
        tvnacimiento.setText(vnacimiento);
        tvinseminacion.setText(vinseminacion);
        tvtoro.setText(vtoro);
        tvestatus.setText(vestatus);
        tvnotas.setText(vnotas);

        tvbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Update();
            }
        });

    }

    private void Update() {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vacas");
        Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        updates.put("inte", tvinterno);
        ref.updateChildren(updates);
    }


}
```

I have added a `button` to the layout, it has to save the edited values to firebase with the `public void Update`, Im doing something wrong, but in my short (almost nil) experience i can't see the error. also, i'm looking for a asesor who can guide me in my project,  if someone want to talk about it, send me an email  to:  pjcm97@outlook.com

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database stores JSON data. You're trying to write an `EditText` object to it, which is not JSON data. So your code is most likely crashing.

```
private void Update() {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Vacas");
    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    updates.put("inte", tvinterno.getText().toString());
    ref.updateChildren(updates);
}
```

I also highly recommend always checking the result of a write operation, to see if it succeeded, as shown in the documentation on [adding a completion listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback).

Comment: Yes, my code is crashing, I added `getText(),tostring()..` I opened a "cow" with the respective information, edit the value `interno` and what happened was that a new key called ** inte ** appears with the new value that I had edited. Im not taking the nodes  `interno`, `siiniga`, `madre`, `padre`... that i have in my database